# show lines from logcat in android app with colours

Tags: android, bufferedreader, logcat

I have encountered a weird problem, trying to show my logcat data with colours in my android app.

What I've done to show the data in the app is this:

```
private class LoadLogCatData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

     try {
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

          log = new StringBuilder();
          String line = ""; 
          int count = 0;

          while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String lineType = line.substring(0, 1);
            String insertLine = "";

            if (lineType.equals("E")) {
                insertLine = "<font color=#ff0000>" + line + "</font>";
            } else if (lineType.equals("W")) {
                insertLine = "<font color=#ffa500>" + line + "</font>";
            } else if (lineType.equals("D")) {
                insertLine = "<font color=#000080>" + line + "</font>"; 
            } else if (lineType.equals("I")) {
                insertLine = "<font color=#006400>" + line + "</font>";    
            } else {
                insertLine = "<font color=#000000>" + line + "</font>";             
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                log.append("<b>" + insertLine + "</b><br>");        
            } else {
                log.append(count + ": " + insertLine + "<br>");
            }

            count++;
          }   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    logArea.setText(Html.fromHtml(log.toString()));
    progressRing.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

For some reason, the data is shown in the right colors until `line logcat 738`. After that, everything is in dark blue color.

What I first thought was wrong, was that it maybe read the rest of the data as a single string and therefore didn't recognized what type of line it was.
But that was not the case as "count" (line no.) was still printed out correctly, which means that every line is handled, but for some reason is given the color blue.

I tried to "syso" out every line, which gave me all the correct colors.. printed out something like this:

```
D: BLUE
D: BLUE
W: ORANGE
I: GREEN
... And so on
```

I hope someone can see what the problem is. 
Thanks in advance.